# A mapping of two sequences with no overlaps and partial assignments

Tags: functions, order-theory, monotone-functions

I want to characterize a correspondence mapping of two sequences $\psi : A \rightarrow B$ for an article that I am writing.

I need help describing the function class.  I think this is an *injective, non-surjective, order isomorphism*. Please correct me on this?

In the figure below I have visually described the constraints on $\psi$ adopting the representation language of the following article: https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/injective-surjective-bijective.html

[image]

Constraints on the mapping, $\psi$. The gray arrows within each sequence indicate ordering within each sequence. This information is repeated in the text.

**Constraints:**

1. First and last elements of each sequence must correspond.  Given that $A$ has length $n$, and $B$ has length $m$: It can be said that $A(1) \widehat{=} B(1)$ and $A(n) \widehat{=} B(m)$.
2. Every element in $A$ has **at most** one element in $B$. Not every element in $A$ can be assigned.
3. The elements of $B$ can have **at most** one assignment.
4. The assignments $A_i \rightarrow B_j$ cannot cross other assignments. That is if $A_i \widehat{=} B_j$ then $A_{i+1} \rightarrow B_k,\ \exists k > j$

Thank you.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Comment: @Shaun - Thank you for your guidance.  I have focused on a single question and removed superfluous comments.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have two sequences: \begin{gather*}
a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \\
b_1, b_2,b_3,b_4,\dots,b_m
\end{gather*}  You want to associate to each value $a_j$ a corresponding value $b_{k(j)}$.

The use of $a_j$ and $b_j$ is tripping you up; IMHO it makes more sense to work on the level of indices.  Instead of associating $a_j$ with $b_k$, associate $j$ with $k$.  The difficulty here is that then one cannot distinguish an index $j$ for $a_j$ from the same index $j$ for $b_j$; I will use $a_j$ and $b_j$ when I risk such confusion, but just $j$ otherwise.

There is no standard notation for association, but I will use $\sim$, because it is the standard notation for graph adjacency.  Pretty much any relation can be described by a graph; you cannot use functions to describe your sort of association because they must associate to every $a_j$ some $b_k$ (or associate to every $b_k$ some $a_j$).

Working with indices, you want to count a certain class of bipartite graphs on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,m\}$: those for which the arrows do not cross in the natural embedding into the plane, for which $a_1\sim b_1$ and $a_n\sim b_m$.

Each arrow is constrained by the one below and the one above it: that is, in the following diagram, the only "free parameters" are the lengths of the red jumps.  [image: Match a1 to b1, a3 to b2, a4 to b4 and a5 to b5. Each matching is indicated by a purple line; there are curved red lines over skipped elements.]

That is, fix $N$; we will have $N$ jumps, each of size $x_s$.  You want to count solutions to $$\sum_{s=1}^N{x_s}=n-1; x_s\geq1\tag{*}$$  Say that there are $f_N(n)$ solutions to (*).

We have to choose jumps on the left and on the right, but there are the same number of jumps on each (because the number of jumps corresponds to the number of matchings, and each matching has a left and a right side).  So there are $f_N(n)f_N(m)$-many jump orders; since $N$ was chosen arbitrarily, we want $$\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}{f_N(n)f_N(m)}$$  (Don't be scared by the infinite sum!  Most terms are $0$.)

We can then count $f_N(n)$ using the famous "stars-and-bars" trick.  Alternatively, if you want to enumerate these matchings, then the above is entirely constructive:

1. Iterate over $N$.  For each $N$:
2. Iterate over all (well, some) numbers.  For each number:
3. Convert that number to a binary sequence.
4. Split the binary sequence in the middle.  Now you have two binary sequences.
5. Use stars-and-bars to convert each binary sequence to a solution to (*).
6. Take the cumulative sum of your solution to (*) to get an association.

I leave you to fill in the details, especially the bounds on steps (1-2).

Comment: First, Thank you for the effort you put into your analysis.  I am wondering if you were confused by my original multipart question?  @shaun pointed out that I was confusing.  Forgive me?  I have fixed this.

It looks like you are answering the question: "How would one count the number of matches?"  I like your use of jumps, btw.  Nice approach.   I think I will adopt your graph adjacency notation. 

My question is about the function class for the mapping that I described.  

Please help me know what I can clarify? - Thank you!

Comment: @CraigChamplin: (1) As I said in the answer, the class of relations you study are not functions (partial functions, yes; functions, no).  (2) There is no common name for that class of relations either; it is too specific a problem.  (3) With no name, the best one can hope to do is give a description of how to generate elements of the class.  That's what I tried to illustrate with my algorithm at the end.

Comment: That is the confirmation that I needed, "give a description of how to generate elements of the class".  Thank you!  Is my description of how to generate this class clear enough?

Comment: @CraigChamplin: Personally, I would prefer to describe it rather constructively: "elementwise pairings of two equal-length subsequences from $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^n$ and $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^m$."  But OTOH I could (eventually) figure out what you were asking, so maybe your original description suffices.  Make sure to include lots of examples in your paper and maybe ask a few friends to read it over; they'll notice if it's still unclear.

Comment: Thank you!  I have been wrapped up in this for months now.  You have given me the confidence to move forward.  I am in your debt!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!!